# R data table combining lapply with other j arguments

Tags: r, data.table

I want to combine the result of lapply using `.SD` in j with further output columns in `j.` How can I do that in the same data table? 
So far Im creating two data tables `(example_summary1, example_summary2)` and merge them but there should be a better way? 
Maybe I don't fully understand the concept of `.SD/.SDcols.`

```
 example <-data.table(id=rep(1:5,3),numbers=rep(1:5,3),sample1=sample(20,15,repla    ce=TRUE),sample2=sample(20,15,replace=100))

     id numbers sample1 sample2
 1:  1       1      17      18
 2:  2       2       8       1
 3:  3       3      17      12
 4:  4       4      15       2
 5:  5       5      14      18
 6:  1       1      11      14
 7:  2       2      12      12
 8:  3       3      11       7
 9:  4       4      16      13
10:  5       5      17       1
11:  1       1      10       3
12:  2       2      14      15
13:  3       3      13       3
14:  4       4      17       6
15:  5       5       1       5


example_summary1<-example[,lapply(.SD,mean),by=id,.SDcols=c("sample1","sample2")]

      > example_summary1
   id  sample1   sample2
1:  1 12.66667 11.666667
2:  2 11.33333  9.333333
3:  3 13.66667  7.333333
4:  4 16.00000  7.000000
5:  5 10.66667  8.000000


example_summary2<-example[,.(example.sum=sum(numbers)),id]

> example_summary2
   id example.sum
1:  1           3
2:  2           6
3:  3           9
4:  4          12
5:  5          15
```

Comment: How many columns do you have?

Comment: in my real data I have about 42 columns which I want to handle with `.SDcols` and some other columns which I want to include to the j output list.

Comment: Those columns interfer with other columns than `SDcols`. I'm not sure whether this is possible or can I only make use of `SDcols`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best you can do if you are using `.SDcols`:

```
example_summary1 <- example[, c(lapply(.SD, mean), .(example.sum = sum(numbers))),
                          by = id, .SDcols = c("sample1", "sample2", "numbers")][, numbers := NULL][]
```

If you don't include `numbers` in `.SDcols` it's not available in j.

Without `.SDcols` you can do this:

```
example_summary1 <- example[, c(lapply(.(sample1 = sample1, sample2 = sample2), mean), 
                               .(example.sum = sum(numbers))),
                            by=id]
```

Or if you have a vector of column names:

```
cols <- c("sample1","sample2")
example_summary1 <- example[, c(lapply(mget(cols), mean), 
                               .(example.sum = sum(numbers))),
                            by=id]
```

But I suspect that you don't get the same data.table optimizations then.

Finally, a data.table join is so fast that I would use your approach.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I don't want to write all SDcols by hand so the later one is not an option. But the first one seems promising. 
I always thought that `.SDcols` only interferes with `.SD`. This restriction is a bit unintuitive.

Comment: `.SD` is a data.table of all columns available in j.

Comment: See my edit for an option if you have a vector of column names.

Comment: "`.SD` is a data.table of all columns available in j" this is no longer true... now all columns are always available in `j`, even if `.SDcols` restricts `.SD` to only keep a subset